# Which one do you want to eat, pizza or noodles? VS What do you want to eat, pizza or noodles?

Tags: grammaticality

I've been asked by a colleague which one of those is correct or if they are both corrects. The "what" sentence sounds perfect and natural for me, but the "which" one does not sound right or natural... and for that reason, I just can't explain why I believe so.

If I may ask, are my assumptions right?

Thank you.

Comment: It's the pronoun "one" that is tripping you up. *Which do you prefer (to eat)? Noodles or pizza?* and *What do you want to eat, noodles or pizza?* are both grammatical.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you something:

> Which one do you want to eat, pizza or noodles?
>
> What one do you want to eat, pizza or noodles?
>
> Which do you want to eat, pizza or noodles?
>
> What do you want to eat, pizza or noodles?

The `one` is at home in either one but is not really needed in either.  All four of these are fine.  When you compare how `which` and `what` sound be a little fair and even out the one.